# How to make a custom field show more than 2 decimal places

Tags: acumatica

I've got a custom field and I can't seem to allow you to edit or display more than 2 decimal places. I've confirmed that the DB is storing 6 (and updated the DB directly to have them) but it only displays and allows the edit on 2 places.

Field attributes look like this:

```
[PXDBDecimal(4)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName="LbsPerInch")]
[PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0000")]
```

On the form I have the display format set to 0.0000, but it's still only showing 2 decimal places and then zeros (eg: DB value is 0.2225, displays 0.2200) and when I click to edit it I only get 2 decimal places.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setup for the field in the DAC looks correct. What do you have for the page entry?

I put together a quick example showing 4 fields with different decimal precision.

**DAC**:

```
[PXDBDecimal]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "D1 ()")]
[PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0")]
public virtual Decimal? TestDecimal1 { get; set; }

[PXDBDecimal(2)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "D2 (2)")]
[PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0")]
public virtual Decimal? TestDecimal2 { get; set; }

[PXDBDecimal(4)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "D3 (4)")]
[PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0")]
public virtual Decimal? TestDecimal3 { get; set; }

[PXDBDecimal(6)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "D4 (6)")]
[PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0")]
public virtual Decimal? TestDecimal4 { get; set; }
```

**Page**:

```
<px:PXNumberEdit ID="edD1" runat="server" DataField="TestDecimal1" />
<px:PXNumberEdit ID="edD2" runat="server" DataField="TestDecimal2" />
<px:PXNumberEdit ID="edD3" runat="server" DataField="TestDecimal3" />
<px:PXNumberEdit ID="edD4" runat="server" DataField="TestDecimal4" />
```

**Result**:

[image]

**Database**:

I used DECIMAL(25, 6) or DECIMAL(19, 4) and same results for 4 decimal precision field.

[image]

Comment: That's why I'm so confused, looks like this:  `<px:PXNumberEdit runat="server" ID="CstPXNumberEdit4" DataField="UsrLbsPerInch" />`

Comment: are you displaying the value in a form or a grid? are you sure your have it set as you posted? maybe not published or applied to the site correctly and still just say [PXDBDecimal] using the default precision of 2? If you have what I posted it should show as 4 places. Not sure what else to check.

Comment: Okay, so I don't know what happened, because I've tried every imaginable combination of this, but I created a new field, and set the DAC to decimal(4) before I published the first time...then added a field and now they *BOTH* work. I'm not sure what I did wrong but it does appear to be working now, so thanks so much for your help!

Comment: no problem. sounds like something didn't make it fully published.

Comment: @Brendan is there a way to set the decimals dynamically at runtime? I have a requirement to allow the user to select the number of decimals on a screen, then I'd like to display the grid fields with the selected number of decimals

Comment: @AdriaanDavel you can create your own attribute (inherit from PXDBDecimalAttribute) for use on your field which changes the precision or looks like you can call PXDBDecimalAttribute public static void SetPrecision(PXCache cache, string name, int? precision). Might be easiest to use an attribute and then your dac will still work in other screens such as generic inquires.